# Information Modeling

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-modeling, machine-learning, neural-network, probability

- The sensor module in my project consists of a **rotating camera**, that collects **noisy** information about **moving objects** in the surrounding environment.
- The information consists of **distance**, **angle** and **relative change** of the moving objects..
- The **limiting view range** of the camera makes it essential to rotate the camera periodically to update environment information...

I was looking for **algorithms / ways** to model these information, in order to be able to **guess / predict / learn** motion properties of these object..

My current proposed idea is to store last n snapshots of each object in a queue. I take weighted average of positions and velocities of moving object, but I think it is a poor method...

**Can you state some titles that suit this case?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kalman {Extended, unscented, ... } filters](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/media/pdf/kalman_intro.pdf) and [particle filters](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.16.4200&rep=rep1&type=pdf) **only** after reading about Kalman filters.

Kalman filters learn and predict the correct data from noisy data with a  Gaussian assumption, so it may be of use to you. If you need non-Gaussian methods, look at the particle filter.

Comment: Thanks for you helpful response.. I wonder if the particle filter will try to learn environment model.. or I will have to provide environment model and equations to it myself?